# Need ideas/suggestions for validating test cases for a large web application

Tags: manual-testing, web-application

1. I'm currently testing a web application that has 300+ test cases. I'm doing manual validation only. How to prioritize them and to make sure I'm covering 100%?
2. I'm also validating the reports page where I need to compare the data with the UI vs. its files that I download (CSV, Excel, PDF). Also, the table report has chart representation which I have to verify, its UI vs. downloadable files (JPEG/PDF/PNG/PDF). I would like to know how to cover all the scenarios or the strategy to be followed.

Comment: Does 'I' means you are the only QA to execute 300 manual test case ? then you need to refine your team and add more QAs. Or push test automation and concentrate manual testing on critical stuff.

Comment: @PDHide Yes, i am the one to execute those test cases. Even though reasonable timeline is given, i couldn't cover all the possible scenrios. During previous work, same thing happened and there were some missed part. This made me to discuss with experts here to get suggestions. Also please suggest some ideas on how automation works out for this.

Comment: Why weren't you able to cover it, even with a timeline that you felt as reasonable? could you mention that in your question

Comment: "Timeline was reasonable" conflicts with "I couldn't cover all the possible scenarios".  The question is: WHY couldn't you cover them all? Not enough time? Not organized enough? Not clear enough about testing?  You can't "fix" a problem until you describe exactly what it is.  Was the timeline set by you or did someone else decide the timeline for your?.  Further discussion will be required is the answer.

Comment: "300+ test cases" is a meaningless piece of information. A test case is only a document explaining some testing procedures. Any number of test cases means nothing in relation to the effort to integrate them into a testing session. Additionally, you haven't added any context, such as tech stack, organizational structure, skills, testability, observability. Without it, you seem to be asking for a best practice, which doesn't exist, since practices' value depends on the context. I would suggest you adding information that makes your question actually actionable.

Comment: Not answering your question directly but it will greatly help you prioritizing: [37 Sources for Test Ideas](http://thetesteye.com/posters/TheTestEye_SourcesForTestIdeas.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't cover 100%.
Now, the answer to your question is that prioritize your test case according to your web application. 
I.e. check the highest priority test case. 
Secondly, check with issues that occur mostly in the application.
Thirdly, check the cases which can impact to other processes.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a common question in a software testing company. However you can easily cover and manage 300 test cases of the application. Below are some of the points which will help you out:
   1.1 Identify the critical modules of the application.
   1.2 Prioritize the TestCases.(Like P1,P2....)
   1.3 Re-factor the testcases.
   1.4 Create Sanity and Regression test cases.
   1.5 Run the testcases w.r.t the build iteration.
2. Your second question is also related to test cases. You need to create the test cases w.r.t to each validation and then compare the same.